# 404 status code and its double meaning on a common-almost-restful api

Tags: api, http, rest

In a truly restful application I should follow links to reach my resources, while the only "magical already known URL" should be the application entry point. Direct queries like `GET /user/john` should be issued after having at least a link to `/user` or as a result from a search url specified by a previous link, like `GET /user?username=john`

But as following links forces more features, further development time and a smarter client, the actual reality is that most of the restful apis that I have written and used are partially restful: they are a collection of well defined URIs and methods, all previously known to the user by some documentation. In the end, the `State Transfer` part of [what REST means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Concept) is not present in most of them.

Well, following that reality where URLs are previously known, the `404` code turns to be an issue: How to differentiate the 2 meanings that `404` can have:

- A [correct `404`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#404) that means *"Resource not found, but you can try again in the future"*. Example: `GET /user/mario` while mario is not a registered user
- A incorrect usage of the api that means *"No resource will ever be found here, you are using this API incorrectly"*. Example: `GET /foobar/123`

It is kinda important to differentiate those two scenarios because as a service maintainer, they are basically telling me if its an expect error and I should not be worried (first case) or an unexpected error and I should be worried as the service integration with my clients has issues (second case)

I tried searching for a better status code to represent the second case, and the closest ones I found were the `406 Not Acceptable` (but it is a response directed to an `Accept` header that cannot be fulfilled) and the `410 Gone` (that can be confusing as no resource was there, but the good part is that it tells the client to never try that URL again). Nevertheless, none of the two are good enough to be used for solving this

How did you or would you do to solve that?

**Side node**: [python eve](http://python-eve.org/) is an interesting project that tries to be a restful api with the `State Transfer` part. It [implements HATEOAS](http://python-eve.org/features.html#hateoas) for that

Comment: In the last example with the incorrect usage, when would this happen? It sounds to me that this one should return a `405` - that's at least what our API does if I'm for instance calling an endpoint with a wrong HTTP method (calling a method with a `POST` request, but the method only allows `GET` requests e.g.).
W3 suggests, that you should return a `410` for when a resource is permanently moved and will never be at the given path anymore: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html - why is `410` confusing?

Comment: 410 means something was previously present at the URL but no longer is, so don't retry the URL ever again. That is not useful if there was nothing previously at the URL but then something appears at a later time.

Comment: Agreed with Remy, the 410 is bad because it tells the client that is a valid url for something that is not there anymore, while the real cause is that the url is malformed and thus always wrong

Comment: `405` almost nails it. It is a `Method not allowed` directive while what I need is an `URL not allowed` directive. Discussion on top of the `403` alternative is probably near to solving this

Comment: +1 for using the term RESTful and saying what you said in the first two paragraphs

Answer (score 2):

What about using `403` for the first case (together with the explanation) and `404` for the second? Since the RFC 403 refers to 404 as an alternative response code they might be related...

> 403 Forbidden: *The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.*
> Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make  public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the  reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, *the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.*

403: You understand what the client wants but refuse to fulfill it. The client should not try again - it's forbidden until this resource is created - which you can explain as part of the answer.

404: You know that the client wants something you won't provide and can tell him in good faith, that this resource will never exists.

**Update:**

[RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119) explains how the "SHOULD NOT" has to be interpreted:

> **SHOULD NOT**   This phrase, or the phrase "NOT RECOMMENDED" mean that
> there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances when the
> particular behavior is acceptable or even useful, but the full
> implications should be understood and the case carefully weighed
> before implementing any behavior described with this label.

I think for your use case this is true. The client request shouldn't be repeated *without solving the reason stated in the 403 answer: "accessing this resource is forbidden because no user named mario exists". But if the client is sure that the reason went away, he is free to try again. But this might be only my interpretation of the `403` "should not be repeated" statement.

Comment: I like the `403` alternative, but what worries me is the *the request SHOULD NOT be repeated* part. In my first example the resource can be found in the requested URL in a matter of time, so the query can be repeated

Comment: Using the `404` for the second case implies that the URL can be repeated. It also goes against common practice, but is not a big issue though and it maybe can solve it. It is something to think of

Comment: Hmm, where do you get that 404 implies that it can be repeated? I considered 404 a "you want something crazy enough that I have no idea how to help you". Like asking me to find the north for you and giving me a plumb because it always points in a certain direction. You might call it "incorrect api usage" - but you might get away with calling it just crazy and be done with it.

Comment: Interesting, the [404 code in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#404) is stated as `The requested resource could not be found but may be available again in the future` while the [RFC it references](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.5) it is `The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.` Well, this means that `404` is simply not time aware of the resource life cycle

Comment: If the URL may be valid at a later time, I would stick with 404, being that it basically means "resource not found RIGHT NOW, I don't know about later".

Comment: I totally agree that 404 would be a valid response - for both cases. The question is: Is there another valid response (e.g. 403 or another) that would  allow to distinguish between these two cases?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to differentiate the two reasons, by design of [RFC 2616 Section 10.4.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.5):

> 10.4.5 404 Not Found
>
> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. **No
>
> indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or
>
> permanent.** The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server
> knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old
> resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
> **This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to
>
> reveal exactly why the request has been refused**, or when no other
> response is applicable.

Comment: What you think about the `403` code, like xworker pointed out in his reply?